# Search through multiple attributes within a json data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, search, full-text-search

I have this incoming data which I need to search.

```
[{:id=>250,
    :application_date=>"02/04/2016",
    :customer_number=>"",
    :customer_name=>"Neymar Silva Junior",
    :city=>"Auckland",
    :region=>"Auckland",
    :service=>"Electricity",
    :name=>"Bosco and Sons",
    :service_plan=>"Electricity Plan",
    :connection_type=>nil,
    :billing_method=>nil,
    :icp_number=>nil,
    :moving_date=>"",
    :supplier_commission=>21.0,
    :show_url=>"/applications/250"},
 {:id=>257,
    :application_date=>"27/05/2016",
    :customer_number=>"",
    :customer_name=>"Ariel name Parra",
    :city=>"Dunedin",
    :region=>"Dunedin",
    :service=>"Electricity",
    :name=>"Bosco and Sons",
    :service_plan=>"Electricity Plan",
    :connection_type=>nil,
    :billing_method=>nil,
    :icp_number=>nil,
    :moving_date=>"28/05/2016",
    :supplier_commission=>21.0,
    :show_url=>"/applications/257"},
 {:id=>291,
    :application_date=>"29/04/2016",
    :customer_number=>"aaaa",
    :customer_name=>"Neymar Silva Junior",
    :city=>"Auckland",
    :region=>"Auckland",
    :service=>"Electricity",
    :name=>"Bosco and Sons",
    :service_plan=>"Electricity Plan",
    :connection_type=>nil,
    :billing_method=>nil,
    :icp_number=>"",
    :moving_date=>"",
    :supplier_commission=>28.0,
    :show_url=>"/applications/291"},
 {:id=>292,
    :application_date=>"29/04/2016",
    :customer_number=>"23223",
    :customer_name=>"Neymar Silva Junior",
    :city=>"Auckland",
    :region=>"Auckland",
    :service=>"Electricity",
    :name=>"Bosco and Sons",
    :service_plan=>"Electricity Plan",
    :connection_type=>nil,
    :billing_method=>nil,
    :icp_number=>"",
    :moving_date=>"",
    :supplier_commission=>21.0,
    :show_url=>"/applications/292"}]
```

I have been able to achieve this.

Store that data in a variable `s`

```
s.select {|h1| h1[:service_plan]=='Electricity Plan'}
```

Now this gives me all those elements which has the matching `service_plan`.

What I want to achieve.

1. If I search with only few words like `Elec` not the entire word it should show the same result.
2. This search should be applied to multiple attributes and not restrict to only one attribute like `service_plan`.

I want to exactly achieve something which we used to do in `Rails active_record` like this:

```
Model.where('attribute_one LIKE :search OR attribute_two LIKE :search OR attribute_three LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%")
```

OR

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ['attribute_one LIKE ? OR attribute_two LIKE ? OR attribute_three LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
```

where `search` is the incoming search parameter.

I want to achieve the same kind of result in a json data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
array.select{ |h| h[:service_plan].include?('Ele') && h[:other_attr].include?('something_word') && h[:other].include?('word') }
```

You can use method `include?('piece_of_word')` on your `string`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) to check substring

```
s.select { |h1| h1.values.any?{ |v| v.to_s.include? 'Elec' } }
```

This will check for presence of `"Elec"` in all the fields and return the records

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```
def select(data, conditions)
  data.select do |d|
    conditions.any? do |attr, val|
      data[attr] && data[attr] =~ /#{val}/
    end
  end
end

# Produces an OR of conditions
select(data, service_plan: 'Elec', service: 'Elec')

# This time an AND
d = select(data, service_plan: 'Elec')
select(d, service: 'Elec')
```